# Why can a C# switch statement not accept the 'dynamic' type?

Tags: c#, dynamic, switch-statement

Since ['At compile time, an element that is typed as dynamic is assumed to support any operation'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx), I would assume that would mean that if I were to use it in a `switch` statement, the compiler would assume that the dynamic variable would be a supported type for a switch statement.

Contrary to my thinking, the statement

```
dynamic thing = "thing";
switch (thing) {
   case "thing": {
      Console.WriteLine("Was a thing.");
      Console.ReadKey();
      break;
   }
   default: {
      Console.WriteLine("Was not thing.");
      Console.ReadKey();
      break;
   }
}
```

Gives the compile time error: `A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type`. So what gives? What's the reason for this limitation?

Comment: Because the "case:" keywords require a value literal/constant. What would be a dynamic literal?

Comment: Because the type that you are switching must be known at compile time. Dynamic values are not known at compile time, only at runtime.

Comment: Why not `switch ((string)thing)` since you clearly already know what the type is?

Comment: I know that is a solution, I was simply curious why the limitation existed.

Comment: As with any feature, the question is never, "why doesn't this feature exist".  Feature are unimplemented by default.  The question is to you, and it is, "why *should* this feature be implemented?"  It is not up to everyone else to justify why your proposed feature *hasn't* been implemented.

Comment: Servy is correct; the language designers are not required to justify the *non-existence* of a feature! Features are expensive and this feature does not produce more value than it would cost, so it was not implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because constants used in the case-labels must be compile time constants compatible with the governing type.

You won't be sure about the `dynamic` variable at the compile time.

How would you know that from which value you will compare in you `case-label` as dynamic variable can hold any type of value.

Look at this

```
dynamic thing = "thing";
//and some later time `thing` changed to
thing = 1;
```

Now think about your case-label (in which type of value you will compare)

Comment: If you're going to quote something, you should cite the origin of that quote.

Answer (score 2):

Because the case statements must contain only constants, if you cast thing to a string:

```
    dynamic thing = "thing";
    switch ((string)thing) {
        case "thing": {
            Console.WriteLine("Was a thing.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            break;
        }
        default: {
            Console.WriteLine("Was not thing.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: agreed...  but was just trying to show how to get it to work.

Comment: He wants to know what's the reason that doesn't allow it, not how to solve it. This is not the answer to the question.

Comment: that doesn't answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because the case statements must contain only constants. Thus limiting the switch only to "native" data (int, double, float, etc.) and strings.
Dynamic may hold all kinds of data including reference types.

Answer (score 0):

Since C# 8 you can use pattern matching switch expressions for this:

```cs
dynamic thing;

thing switch
{
    int intThing => $"it's an int, incremented: {intThing + 1}",
    string stringThing => $"it's a string, uppercase: {stringThing.ToUpper()}",
    _ => "I have no idea what this is"
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Upgrade your VS, In VS 2017 switch statement has accepted the dynamic type.

Happy coding :)

Comment: What do different versions of Visual Studio have to do with the language specifications? Or do you mean any specific version of C# which has this feature?